# after change value in checkbox date pop out

Tags: excel, excel-formula, checkbox, google-docs

In checkbox I have two values (YES/NO). Default value is "NO". After swapping value from "NO" to "YES" today's date should pop out. I was working with function `TODAY()` but problem is editing it a day after. Every single date has changed to todays.

For example:

- yesterday 16.07 - I flipped 200 records from "YES" to "NO". So, there is 16.07 as a date.
- today 17.07 - I flipped another 200 records but 400 has todays date.

code:

```
=IF($A1="YES";TODAY();"-")
```

I tried to convert it do text instead of date but result was the same.

Is there any way to do this with just formulas or I should try to do this with `VBA`?

Comment: VBA is the way to go.  Formula are live which means if the input changes, so will the output.  With the input of `TODAY()` which is volatile, it will change anytime something in Excel changes.

Answer (score 0):

This is doable without VBA if you are willing to use circular references on your spreadsheet.
Referring to this page https://www.exceldemy.com/insert-static-date-in-excel/

(method 3)

First of all, go to File ➤ Options.
As a result, the Excel Options dialog box will pop out.
In the Formulas tab, check the box for Enable iterative calculation as marked below.
Afterward, press OK.

select the cell where you want to populate the date, lets say its cell b2, and the yes/ no values are entered in a2

Type the following formula in B2

```
=IF(A2="Yes", IF(B2="",TODAY(),B2),"")
```

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: One should note, that changing the setting to allow circular references is at the app level and not the workbook or worksheet.  In other words, you are now allowing circular references through out all Excel.  It is also not something that is saveable to the workbook.  Each user will have to change that setting manually BEFORE opening the workbook or they will all change to 0.  This is not a very user friendly method, which is why vba is a much better option as it is saveable to the workbook and only affects the cells desired.